# Warning: Illegal string offset ‘content’

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, composer-php

As a graphics designer I'm not too savvy when it comes to PHP code.

> Warning: Illegal string offset ‘content’ in *webaddress/class-vc-frontend-editor.php* on line 908

I'm using the front end editor for Visual Composer and I keep getting this error coming up when inspecting the code i get the following:

```
 );
        if ( false !== WPBMap::getParam( $s, 'content' ) ) {
            $shortcode['attrs']['content'] = $s 'content';
        }
```

I am a competent with HTML, CSS and Scripter but I'm hoping someone with advanced PHP skills will be able to answer my question.

If I open the file up in Dreamweaver to attempt to diagnose the error, I get the following:

> line 908 : syntax error, unexpected quoted-string (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

What is wrong with this code so that it throws this error message up?

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `.` character at:

```
$shortcode['attrs']['content'] = $s.'content';
```

Here the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) about string operators.

Comment: thanks for your help guys much appreciate, hope i can return the favour at some point :D

Answer (score 0):

It appears there are at least two errors with this code. See the list items below for explanations.

1. The error in the question title:

   > Warning: Illegal string offset ‘content'

   This comes from indexing into an array that doesn't have an offset at the specified index.

   > ```
   > $shortcode['attrs']['content'] = $s 'content';
   > ```

   If `$shortcode['attrs']` is not an array or does not have an element at index 'content', then this error will occur. You didn't explain where `$shortcode` comes from but one way to avoid this error is to check if the array has an index at *content* using [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/array_key_exists):

   ```
   if (array_key_exists('content', $shortcode['attrs'])) {
       $shortcode['attrs']['content'] = $s 'content';
   }
   else {
       //handle case where index isn't defined
   }
   ```

   To be even safer, it might be wise to ensure that is an array with [is_array()](http://php.net/is_array):

   ```
   if (is_array($shortcode['attrs']) && array_key_exists('content', $shortcode['attrs'])) {
   ```
2. The second error you mentioned:

   > line 908 : syntax error, unexpected quoted-string (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

   This occurs because on the right-hand side of the assignment (in that same line) the variable `$s` precedes the string literal (i.e. `'content'`) with no operator between. I don't know what exactly you want to do with those two operands but perhaps they should be concatenated. That can be achieved with the [string operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) *dot* (i.e. `.`).

   ```
   $shortcode['attrs']['content'] = $s . 'content';
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For the people coming here asking this question:

1. the correct line should be `$shortcode['attrs']['content'] = $content;`
2. the error is due to VC that does not retrieve the content in the regex, few lines before:

   ```
   $shortcode = array(
           'tag' => $s,
           'attrs_query' => $found[3][ $index ],
           'attrs' => shortcode_parse_atts( $found[3][ $index ] ), //here
           'id' => $id,
           'parent_id' => $parent_id,
       );
   ```